# C# List of base type add generic children instance

Tags: c#, list, generics, inheritance

I have a base class `MessageBase`

```
public abstract class MessageBase {}
```

`Message1D` and `Message2D` inherit from `MessageBase`

```
public class Message1D : MessageBase {}
public class Message2D : MessageBase {}
```

I also have a generic class `Foo` with a generic parameter of type `MessageBase`

```
public abstract class Foo<T> where T : MessageBase {}
```

And two classes `Bar` and `Baz`:

```
public class Bar : Foo<Message1D> {}
public class Baz : Foo<Message2D> {}
```

And my problem is here:

```
public class Network
{
    private List<Foo<MessageBase>> messages = new List<Foo<MessageBase>>();

    public void AddBar()
    {
        messages.Add(new Bar()); //can not add 
    }

    public void AddBaz()
    {
        messages.Add(new Baz()); //can not add 
    }
}
```

Since `Bar` and `Baz` inherit from `Foo<T>` and T is of type `MessageBase` I would expect I should be able to add `Bar` and `Baz` instances to the List, however I can not due to:

> Can not convert from `Bar` to `Foo<MessageBase>`

and

> Can not convert from `Baz` to `Foo<MessageBase>`

I want to add `Bar` and `Baz` instances to the List. How can I do that ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @vasily.sib I want to add Bar and Baz instances to the list. How can I do that ?

Comment: `Foo<Message1D>` is not inherited from `Foo<MessageBase>`, so you can't right now. You may add some common interface to `Foo<Message1D>` and `Foo<Message2D>` and change diffinition of your `messages` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this case, you should declare `interface IFoo<out T>` instead of `abstract class Foo<T>`. **out** keyword, which means **covariance**, will allow you to perform desired operations, i.e. casting `Bar`/`Baz` classes, which implement `IFoo<Message1D>`/`IFoo<Message2D>`, to `IFoo<MessageBase>` interface:

```
public abstract class MessageBase { }    

public class Message1D : MessageBase { }
public class Message2D : MessageBase { }

public interface IFoo<out T> where T : MessageBase { }

public class Bar : IFoo<Message1D> { }
public class Baz : IFoo<Message2D> { }    

public class Network
{
    private List<IFoo<MessageBase>> messages = new List<IFoo<MessageBase>>();

    public void AddBar()
    {
        messages.Add(new Bar());
    }

    public void AddBaz()
    {
        messages.Add(new Baz());
    }
}
```